# How do I copy the structure and contents of some tables from one database to another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

How do I copy the structure and contents of the tables below in SQL Server Management Studio from database `SNO_TEST` to `SNO_TMP` (on the same server)?

The names of the tables are `ADMIN_ErrorLog`, `AdminMissingFiles` and `SNO_QAErrorCategory`

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to copy the *structure and contents* of 3 tables from one database to another? On the same server or different servers? What version of SQL?

Comment: Yes structure and contents of 3 tables from one to another database on the same server and the version is Sql server 12. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I would have assumed there was already a question on this, but I couldn't find a general one for SQL Server, just narrowly tailored ones, or ones for other platforms.)

The method I chose would probably depend on how big the tables are, and also whether there are any other objects associated with the tables (like indexes, triggers, constraints, etc.). But here are a few methods that might work:

1. **Use the "Import/Export Wizard".**

This is probably the simplest. Right click the source database and go to **Tasks > Export Data...** I'm not going to walk through all the steps of the wizard here, but you can select the source and destination databases, then choose which tables you want to copy. [Here's a page that walks through a simple example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/get-started-with-this-simple-example-of-the-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017), although they are using it for importing data from Excel.

After copying the data, add any necessary indexes/constraints/etc.

2. **Do a `SELECT INTO`**

With very small tables, I'll just do a very quick:

```
SELECT *
INTO myDestinationDB.dbo.tablename
FROM mySourceDB.dbo.tablename
```

Replacing with your database names and table names, of course.

This creates the destination tables on the fly. You'll need to add indexes/constraints yourself afterwards. Also be aware that this won't always work for some limited situations like identity columns.

3. **Script out the table definition, then do an `INSERT INTO`**

Right-click the table in the source database, and choose "**Script Table as > Create To > New Query Editor Window**"

Then change the `USE databasename` at the top to your destination database, and run the `CREATE` statement to create the table. Now is your chance to also add indexes or constraints, if necessary. Then to copy the data, do something like:

```
INSERT INTO myDestinationDB.dbo.tablename
SELECT * FROM mySourceDB.dbo.tablename
```

If these tables have millions and millions of rows, definitely use the 1st method above, or use an advanced technique like a custom SSIS package (not covered in this answer), otherwise you might fill up your transaction log.

Hope this leads you in the right direction. Good luck.

Comment: An additional option for SQL Server 2016 SP2+ is to use `DBCC CLONEDATABASE` with the `VERIFY_CLONEDB` option, followed by an INSERT … SELECT into the empty table in the new database.